# Javascript Function to add/remove fields

Tags: javascript, forms, function, dynamic, w3c

I'm not very experienced with JavaScript, but this code was similar to what I was looking for , especially where it includes the 'Remove Field' link.  Here is the Javscript function:

```
//Add more fields dynamically.
function addField(field,area,limit) {
    if(!document.getElementById) return; //Prevent older browsers from getting any further.
    var field_area = document.getElementById(area);
    var all_inputs = field_area.getElementsByTagName("input"); //Get all the input fields in the given area.
    //Find the count of the last element of the list. It will be in the format '<field><number>'. If the 
    //      field given in the argument is 'friend_' the last id will be 'friend_4'.
    var last_item = all_inputs.length - 1;
    var last = all_inputs[last_item].id;
    var count = Number(last.split("_")[1]) + 1;

    //If the maximum number of elements have been reached, exit the function.
    //      If the given limit is lower than 0, infinite number of fields can be created.
    if(count > limit && limit > 0) return;

    if(document.createElement) { //W3C Dom method.
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.id = field+count;
        input.name = field+count;
        input.type = "text"; //Type of field - can be any valid input type like text,file,checkbox etc.
        li.appendChild(input);
        field_area.appendChild(li);
    } else { //Older Method
        field_area.innerHTML += "<li><input name='"+(field+count)+"' id='"+(field+count)+"' type='text' /></li>";
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML for the form:

```
<form name="frm" method="POST">
<strong>Neutral List</strong><br />
<ol id="neutrals_area">
<li><input type="text" name="neutral_1" id="neutral_1" /> <a style="cursor:pointer;color:blue;" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">Remove Field</a></li>
<li><input type="text" name="neutral_2" id="neutral_2" /> <a style="cursor:pointer;color:blue;" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">Remove Field</a></li>
<li><input type="text" name="neutral_3" id="neutral_3" /> <a style="cursor:pointer;color:blue;" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">Remove Field</a></li>
<li><input type="text" name="neutral_4" id="neutral_4" /> <a style="cursor:pointer;color:blue;" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">Remove Field</a></li>
<li><input type="text" name="neutral_5" id="neutral_5" /> <a style="cursor:pointer;color:blue;" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">Remove Field</a></li>
</ol>
<input type="button" value="Add Neutral Field" onclick="addField('neutrals_area','neutral_',0);" />
</form>
```

However, I would like the additional fields to generate with the 'Remove Link' code, not just the ones with code in the script.  I understand that the custom functions have to be adjusted to include that behavior, but am having all kinds of trouble trying to get that function to work.  It seems straightforward to do it in the older method following the "} else {" at the bottom of the addField function by editing the code to read:

```
} else { //Older Method
    field_area.innerHTML += "<li><input name='"+(field+count)+"' id='"+(field+count)+"' type='text' /><a style="cursor:pointer;color:blue;" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">Remove Field</a></li>";
}
```

However, I'm stumped as to how to include it in the W3C DOM method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to differ with Kappa and encourage you strongly to keep doing what you're doing. JQUery is great for what it is, but it is too often a crutch, and it's so important to know what you're doing and why you're doing it when working with javascript. Especially if you are learning to get a job in the sector, you will need straight JavaScript.

The good news, what you're trying to do is actually quite simple!

```
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.id = field+count;
    input.name = field+count;
    input.type = "text"; //Type of field - can be any valid input type like text,file,checkbox etc.
    li.appendChild(input);
    field_area.appendChild(li);
    //create the removal link
    removalLink = document.createElement('a');
    removalLink.onclick = function(){
        this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)
    }
    removalText = document.createTextNode('Remove Field');
    removalLink.appendChild(removalText);
    li.appendChild(removalLink);
```

Here's the code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r9bRT/

Comment: Thank you.  I will give this a try.  This looks straightforward.  I'm hoping to make it more complicated once I understand the core of what I'm doing.  Specifically, a group of three fields that can be added or removed as needed as a group (e.g., a car make, engine type, and make year)

Comment: For learning purpose i do agree with hand made plain js solutions, but for production I can't see why not relying on clean, lightweight and well tested libraries.

Comment: Okay, I worked with your code and got it to work with three related fields in a group.  http://jsfiddle.net/wtX7Y/15/   Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Remove those `if(!document.getElementById)` and `if(document.createElement)` conditions. Every browser supports them, and those which not are not worth to be supported (Let them throw their errors).

To add the remove-method to DOM-created elements, just use the `onclick` property. You can also use [standard-compliant addEventListner()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener), but this needs some workarounds for IE. See sections [Legacy Internet Explorer and attachEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent) and [Older way to register event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Older_way_to_register_event_listeners).

So the code would be

```
...
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" ");
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Remove Field"));
a.style = "cursor:pointer;color:blue;";
a.onclick = function() {
    // this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
    // nay. we have better references to those objects:
    field_area.removeChild(li);
};
li.appendChild(a);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wtX7Y/2/

Comment: I was definitely trying something similar, but was getting caught up in the "a." syntax.  I'll try this as well.  Thank you.  I will definitely follow up, after I try it.

Answer (score -2):

I strongly suggest you to take a look to jQuery (ora similar: prototype, motools etc..)

They have full featured DOM manipulation functionalities, that makes what you ask as complex as writing 1 line of js.

Comment: No need for jQuery to create such a simple functionality.

Comment: I've used some jQuery for form validation, mostly the "remote" function to check against existing database entries with PHP.  I didn't know it could do things like this.  I do want to understand the JavaScript of it, but any solution will do.  I think my form will likely get more complicated with three related fields that I want to add together and remove together (for instance, three related fields for a car make, engine type, and make year).

Comment: Bergi read my comment on Chris Sobolewski solution. Then think that when making first steps in a software you cannot imagine how in future that situation will become; so i always try to get the best solution that will allow me to make easy any further change.

Comment: kappa - could you point me in the right direction with respect to doing this in jQuery.  I'd like to know how to do it both ways, and your point is well taken regarding ease of updating.  Thanks